# How can I delete a table with Komodo MySQL plugin?

Tags: mysql, constraints, komodo, dml, return-code

I've setup a Komodo remote database server with a MySQL plugin loaded and I want to empty a table. I select the table and change to the "query" tab in the MySQL plugin, but when I run "truncate table;" it does nothing. I've allowed deletion of the "full table", but I cannot delete all selected rows in the "full table" either. It gives me a KeyError: 150 or KeyError: 84?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) or remove any [foreign key constraints or checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452760/truncate-foreign-key-constrained-table) before attempting to TRUNCATE.