# Query for deleting ALL data from a database on MySQL using VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

What's the query to delete **all** data from a database? The reason for this is there are tons of data that will be processed and stored on that database and every month it should be cleaned in order to avoid having tons of data as the previous data will be irrelevant on the next cycle.

PS, is there such a query as:

```
Dim sqlQuery As String = "DELETE ALL * FROM employee_table"
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651867/mysql-delete-all-rows-from-table-and-reset-id-to-zero) but I don't think it's the answer to what I'm looking to do.

Comment: I have closed your previous question as a duplicate. It seems pretty clear what you need to do. Send a MySqlCommand to your database with the `TRUNCATE TABLE tablename`. What is not clear in that?

Comment: No steve, it is not clear to me because I am not as smart as you when it comes to programming. What I got from that is I thought that there are other conditions after the TRUNCATE TABLE tablename part. At least T.J Crowder answered properly, his answer is helpful and not rude.

Answer (score 1):

> PS, is there such a query as:
>
> `Dim sqlQuery As String = "DELETE ALL * FROM employee_table"`

Yes:

```
Dim sqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM employee_table"
```

That records the delete (in replication logs, etc.) like any other data modification. You might also see:

```
Dim sqlQuery As String = "TRUNCATE TABLE employee_table"
```

That does **not** record the delete (in replication logs, etc.).

See [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/) for the difference between an unqualified `DELETE` (a `DELETE` with no `WHERE`) and a `TRUNCATE`, but basically: If you use replication, binlogs, etc. and need to have an accurate reflection of the actons that occurred, use `DELETE`; if you don't need that, you can use `TRUNCATE`, which operates more quickly (since it doesn't have to do the logging and such).

> Query for deleting ALL data from a database...

The above is, of course, just for one table. To do multiple tables, just use multiple `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE` statements.

Comment: Also, if you are using `safe update mode` then MySQL will not allow `delete` without `where`

Comment: @Rahul: Yeah, but that's at the command line, not through a connector.

Comment: I am not sure about connector but good to know though. Just thought of putting as comment an extra info on this.

Comment: So, why use `TRUNCATE TABLE`? I know thew answer but it would augment your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can enumerate all the db tables and then delete its content.

To enumerate the tables you can do "SHOW TABLES;",  and then iterate throug the results and truncate those tables "TRUNCATE TABLE (tablename);"

Beware of relationships, if a row is referenced by a foreign key you will not be allowed to delete it, so you must delete the info hierarchically.