# how can delete table data without deleting columnnames

Tags: mysql

How can I delete table data, but not delete the table column names?

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

I have to delete all content of table but the table column names should not be deleted.

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE [condition];
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 16):

Just use

```
DELETE FROM table_name;
```

or

```
DELETE * FROM table_name;
```

If you still want to add condition, you can use following:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE 1=1;
```

Comment: I got an error with `DELETE * FROM table_name;` but the first option with the * works perfectly. Strange, but thanks.

Answer (score 5):

> **Bibliography:**
>   SQL - TRUNCATE TABLE Command http://goo.gl/YN7N9Y
>   SQL - Syntax http://goo.gl/viyYFU

The SQL `TRUNCATE TABLE` command is used to delete complete data from an existing table.

You can also use DROP TABLE command to delete complete table but it would remove complete table structure form the database and you would need to re-create this table once again if you wish you store some data.

Syntax:

The basic syntax of `TRUNCATE TABLE` is as follows:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE  table_name;
```

Example:
Consider the CUSTOMERS table having the following records:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Following is the example to truncate:

```
SQL > TRUNCATE TABLE CUSTOMERS;
```

Now, CUSTOMERS table is truncated and following would be the output from SELECT statement:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Truncate is not transaction safe, will not invoke delete triggers,implicit commit,it is almost like drop and recreate. so better not to use.

Comment: @TirupathiRaju, truncate is used just for DB development case, avoiding production case, We could use it. :)

Comment: if that is the case it should be fine. But make a note even it will not give info on how many rows deleted. Ofcourse Truncate will happen few seconds when compared to delete row by row

Answer (score 5):

This is equivalent to DELETE statement:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE yourTableName;
```

Comment: Truncate is not transaction safe, will not invoke delete triggers,implicit commit,it is almost like drop and recreate. so better not to use.

Comment: @TirupathiRaju There are cons and pros for DELETE, TRUNCATE and DROP and all of them depend on the implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;

use below link
[mysql-delete-all-rows-from-table-and-reset-id-to-zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651867/mysql-delete-all-rows-from-table-and-reset-id-to-zero)

Answer (score 0):

- If you need to remove specific rows based on conditions and want to maintain transaction safety (**delete offers the rollback option in case of any error**) and trigger execution, **use DELETE**.

```sql
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE condition;
```

- If you want to quickly remove all rows from a table and don't need transaction safety (**truncate does not offer the rollback option**) or trigger execution, and it's acceptable to reset auto-incremented sequences,
  also can **Truncate** dependent tables if the CASCADE option is used.
  **use TRUNCATE**

```sql
TRUNCATE your_table;
```

***Note**: Due to its speed, TRUNCATE is often preferred for removing all rows from a table, especially when dealing with large datasets.