# How to truncate some tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am trying to `TRUNCATE` some `TABLES` in my DB in MySQL, but when I try to do it, there is an error.

Please have in count that I've set the `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECK` to 0, like says in `line 2` and returned back to 1 in `line 9`

Why and how to solve it?

Here my query
[image: My SQL Query that desnt works]

Here is the error I got
[image: The error]

Adding tables structure

```
--
-- Table structure for table `metadata`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `metadata` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user` (`user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=54 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `patients`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `patients` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nss` bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_1st` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name_2nd` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name_1st` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name_2nd` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clinic` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attached` text,
  `valid` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `metadata` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `clinic` (`clinic`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `queue`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `queue` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `consecutive` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `creat_day` date NOT NULL,
  `patient` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `metadata` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `consecutive` (`consecutive`,`creat_day`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `metadata` (`metadata`),
  KEY `patient_ident` (`patient`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `triage_regs`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `triage_regs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `queue` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `patient` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `cod_color` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `medicines` text NOT NULL,
  `time_start_triage` time NOT NULL,
  `time_end_triage` time NOT NULL,
  `tens_arterial` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `frec_card` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `frec_resp` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `temp` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `gluc` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `esc_glasgown` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `atention` varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n/a',
  `questions` longtext,
  `exp_fis` longtext,
  `aux_diag` longtext,
  `pron` longtext,
  `trat` longtext,
  `diag` longtext,
  `status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `metadata` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `metadata2` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `patient` (`patient`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `metadata2` (`metadata2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Comment: please show tables structure

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam updated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452760/truncate-foreign-key-constrained-table/8074510#8074510

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam thats what am doing but actually not working

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly as the error says: You **cannot** truncate a table referenced **BY** a foreign key constraint, being it a WITH CHECK constraint or not. This is because `TRUNCATE` forces the table to be dropped and then created again, and obviously a table which is defined as "master" in a foreign key relationship cannot be dropped, even temporarily.

So what you have to do is **first drop all FK constraints** which reference your table, then TRUNCATE it, then **recreate** the FK constraints.

Comment: But when I do the same with phpmyadmin, I can truncate all the tables I need

Comment: I see; then this is just a problem with MySql, it should never allow such behaviour. But what do I know :-)