# SequelizeDatabaseError: Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am using `"sequelize": "^5.8.6"` and I have defined two models, **company** and **dividend**.

My `company.js` model looks like the following:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Company = sequelize.define('Company', {
    company_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    company_link: DataTypes.STRING,
    ticker: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Company.associate = function(models) {
    Company.hasMany(models.Rating, { onDelete: 'cascade' });
    Company.hasMany(models.Dividend, { onDelete: 'cascade' });
  };
  return Company;
};
```

My `dividend.js` model looks like the following:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Dividend = sequelize.define('Dividend', {
    period: DataTypes.STRING,
    amount: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    payable_date: DataTypes.DATE,
  }, {});
  Dividend.associate = function(models) {
    Dividend.belongsTo(models.Company, { onDelete: 'cascade' });
  };
  return Dividend;
};
```

My `truncate.js` function looks like the following:

```
const models = require('../models');

const truncateTable = (modelName) =>
  models[modelName].destroy({
    where: {},
    force: true,
  });

module.exports = async function truncate(model) {
  if (model) {
    return truncateTable(model);
  }

  return Promise.all(
    Object.keys(models).map((key) => {
      if (['sequelize', 'Sequelize'].includes(key)) return null;
      return truncateTable(key);
    })
  );
}
```

When trying to truncate both models I get the following error:

```
{ SequelizeDatabaseError: Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`test-db`.`dividends`, CONSTRAINT
`dividends_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CompanyId`) REFERENCES `test-db`.`companies` (`id`))
    at Query.formatError (c:\test\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:239:16)
    at Query.handler [as onResult] (c:\test\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:46:23)
    at Query.execute (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:30:14)
    at Connection.handlePacket (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:449:32)
    at PacketParser.Connection.packetParser.p [as onPacket] (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:72:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.Connection.stream.on.data (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:79:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent:
   { Error: Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`test-db`.`dividends`, CONSTRAINT `dividends_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CompanyId`) REFERENCES `test-db`.`companies` (`id`))
       at Packet.asError (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:684:17)
       at Query.execute (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:28:26)
       at Connection.handlePacket (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:449:32)
       at PacketParser.Connection.packetParser.p [as onPacket] (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:72:12)
       at PacketParser.executeStart (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
       at Socket.Connection.stream.on.data (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:79:25)
       at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
       at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
     code: 'ER_TRUNCATE_ILLEGAL_FK',
     errno: 1701,
     sqlState: '42000',
     sqlMessage:
      'Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`test-db`.`dividends`, CONSTRAINT `dividends_ibfk_1`
FOREIGN KEY (`CompanyId`) REFERENCES `test-db`.`companies` (`id`))',
     sql: 'TRUNCATE `Companies`' },
  original:
   { Error: Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`test-db`.`dividends`, CONSTRAINT `dividends_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CompanyId`) REFERENCES `test-db`.`companies` (`id`))
       at Packet.asError (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:684:17)
       at Query.execute (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:28:26)
       at Connection.handlePacket (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:449:32)
       at PacketParser.Connection.packetParser.p [as onPacket] (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:72:12)
       at PacketParser.executeStart (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
       at Socket.Connection.stream.on.data (c:\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:79:25)
       at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
       at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
     code: 'ER_TRUNCATE_ILLEGAL_FK',
     errno: 1701,
     sqlState: '42000',
     sqlMessage:
      'Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`test-db`.`dividends`, CONSTRAINT `dividends_ibfk_1`
FOREIGN KEY (`CompanyId`) REFERENCES `test-db`.`companies` (`id`))',
     sql: 'TRUNCATE `Companies`' },
  sql: 'TRUNCATE `Companies`' }
```

Any suggestions why I get this error?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here you go :**

`sequelize.query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0', null, { raw: true })`

Temporarily disabling referential constraints (set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS to 0) is useful when you need to re-create the tables and load data in any parent-child order.
with `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0`

**Code :**

```
const models = require('../models');

const truncateTable = (modelName) =>
    models[modelName].destroy({
        where: {},
        force: true,
    });

module.exports = async function truncate(model) {
    if (model) {
        return truncateTable(model);
    }
    await sequelize.query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0', null, { raw: true }); //<---- Do not check referential constraints
    return Promise.all(
        Object.keys(models).map((key) => {
            if (['sequelize', 'Sequelize'].includes(key)) return null;
            return truncateTable(key);
        })
    );
}

// once you get the response from truncate, run this, and it will set foreign key checks again
sequelize.query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1', { raw: true }); // <-- Specify to check referential constraints
```

**Flow :**

> - **First  :**  With SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0 -- Do not check referential    constraints
> - **Second :**  So we can destroy all the tables and we'll not    get error    regarding foreign key constraint
> - **Third  :**  once all the    tables got truncate we'll set SET    FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1 back --    Specify to check referential
>     constraints

Answer (score 2):

I think this has nothing to do with Sequelize, but the database instead.

At [How to truncate a foreign key constrained table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452760/how-to-truncate-a-foreign-key-constrained-table), are shown some options to deal with this restriction, that could be applies in a [Sequelize transaction](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/transaction.js~Transaction.html)

Answer (score 1):

I know its quiet late but hope it helps someone. 
I am using sequelize 3.35.1 and this resolved the issue for me:

```
    sequelize = new Sequelize("database_name", "Username", "password");

    sequelize.query('SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;', { raw: true });
    // Do Some Action
    sequelize.query('SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;', { raw: true });
```

Only SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; was not doing the trick for me.