# Laravel Seeder throws SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship, laravel-migrations, laravel-seeding

I am having the following db tables

```
// Table 1: Foos
id, foo_name, foo_type, created_at, updated_at

// Table 2: Bars
id, bar_name, bar_type, parent_id, foo_id [ForeignKey], created_at, updated_at

// Table 3: Quxes
id, qux_name, bar_id [ForeignKey], created_at, updated_at
```

And I am having the following seeders setup

```
class FooSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        \App\Models\Qux::truncate();
        \App\Models\Bar::truncate();
        \App\Models\Foo::truncate();

        \App\Models\Foo::create([
            'foo_name' => 'Foo',
            'foo_type' => 'Foo type',
        ]);
    }
}

class BarSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        \App\Models\Qux::truncate();
        \App\Models\Bar::truncate();

        \App\Models\Bar::create([
            'bar_name' => 'Bar',
            'bar_type' => 'Bar type',
            'foo_id' => 1,
            'parent_id' => 1,
        ]);

        \App\Models\Bar::create([
            'bar_name' => 'Bar Bar',
            'bar_type' => 'Bar Bar type',
            'foo_id' => 1,
            'parent_id' => 0,
        ]);
    }
}


class QuxSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        \App\Models\Qux::truncate();
        \App\Models\Bar::truncate();

        \App\Models\Qux::create([
            'qux_name' => 'Qux',
            'bar_id' => 1,
        ]);

        \App\Models\Qux::create([
            'qux_name' => 'Qux Qux',
            'bar_id' => 1,
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I try to run `php artisan db:seed` I get the following error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`mylaravelschema`.`quxes`, CONSTRAINT `qux_bar_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`bar_id`) REFERENCES `mylaravelschema`.`bars` (`id`)) (SQL: truncate table `bars`)
```

I have been trying to play with the order of truncating the tables on these three seeders and still haven't manage to sort this, any help appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452760/how-to-truncate-a-foreign-key-constrained-table -- You'll need to use a `DB::statement()` to disable the foreign keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this solution

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    protected $tables = [
        'foos',
        'bars',
        'quxes',
    ];

    public function run()
    {
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');

        foreach ($this->tables as $table) {
            DB::table($table)->truncate();
        }

        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');

        $this->call([
            FooSeeder::class,
            BarSeeder::class,
            QuxSeeder::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
class FooSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        \App\Models\Foo::truncate();
        \App\Models\Bar::truncate();
        \App\Models\Qux::truncate();
        

        \App\Models\Foo::create([
            'foo_name' => 'Foo',
            'foo_type' => 'Foo type',
        ]);
    }
}

class BarSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
       

        \App\Models\Bar::create([
            'bar_name' => 'Bar',
            'bar_type' => 'Bar type',
            'foo_id' => 1,
            'parent_id' => 1,
        ]);

        \App\Models\Bar::create([
            'bar_name' => 'Bar Bar',
            'bar_type' => 'Bar Bar type',
            'foo_id' => 1,
            'parent_id' => 0,
        ]);
    }
}


class QuxSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {

        \App\Models\Qux::create([
            'qux_name' => 'Qux',
            'bar_id' => 1,
        ]);

        \App\Models\Qux::create([
            'qux_name' => 'Qux Qux',
            'bar_id' => 1,
        ]);
    }
}
```

please use this hierarchy level because you've the foreign keys and when you're going to truncate it cannot find the reference one
Hope it helps